# API JSON WS in liferay : only chosed json ws can work

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have `json.web.service.enabled=false` and i must not change it.

But i want to get with natives json ws my AssetCategory and my AssetTags. So is it possible to allow only this 2 ws ?

I know if i pass my json.web.service.enabled to true, I can allow only authenticated user to use it. But can I restrict the access to the page api/jsonws to nobody ???

Thanks for your answers and your help.

Comment: If you "restrict the access to the page api/jsonws to nobody," how are AssetCategory and AssetTags be accessible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below portal property in portal-ext.properties to allow only set of web-services.

`#
    # The property "jsonws.web.service.paths.includes" denotes patterns for JSON
    # web service action paths that are allowed. Set a blank pattern to allow
    # any service action path.
    #
    jsonws.web.service.paths.includes=`

To be specific; in order to make AssetCategory and AssetTag related json ws, you would use.
`jsonws.web.service.paths.includes=/assetcategory/*,/assettag/*`

Comment: Thanks, it's a good option. Is it possible to unable the access to the page api/jsonws ?

Comment: @DyM I know this is an old question but maybe the answer will be helpful for someone who accidentally enters this topic ;) You can disable api/jsonws page by setting jsonws.web.service.api.discoverable=false in your portal-ext.properties as described here https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017882172-Configuring-JSON-Web-Services- but unfortunately it only works in 7.0+